# C# generic How to define that T is Base<Tp> : where Tp : Base<Tp> and Call Base<Tp> method

Tags: c#, generic-programming, generics

I have confusing situation.

Base Generic Type and successor

```
public abstract class BaseType<TEntity> : where TEntity : BaseType<TEntity>
public class AnyType : BaseType<AnyType>
```

It looks like a generic loop)))

I need Method like

```
public void Method<T>(T data)
{
if(typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(BaseType<????>))
 convert data to BaseType<???> and exec BaseType<>'s method
else
//Do that
}
```

In generic Method i need to defines that T is BaseType and exec method on it.
How can I do that????

Comment: 10x for replies!
But I need additional feature.
public void Method<T>(T data)
Exec BaseType<> method on Data...
I my use Reflection, but I prefer type conversion to BaseType<>.
Is It possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection and work your way up the hierarchy using [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx). Note that depending on the exact concrete class, the base type could still be an open generic type, e.g.

```
class Foo<T> : BaseType<T>
```

You can use `Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` and `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` to try to work your way to `BaseType<>`. Basically you want to find out whether any class in the inheritance hierarchy has a generic type definition which is `typeof(BaseType<>)`. Just be glad you're not dealing with interfaces, which make the whole thing even harder :)

Comment: 10x for replies! But I need additional feature. public void Method<T>(T data) Exec BaseType<> method on Data... I my use Reflection, but I prefer type conversion to BaseType<>. Is It possible?

Comment: @sh1ng: It's not really clear what you mean. Perhaps you should use `Method<TBase, TItem>`(TBase value) where TBase : BaseType<TItem>`?

Comment: I can't add type constrain to generic method...
If data(param) is BaseType<SuccessorType> then call
 ((BaseType<T>)data).Method() 
else another action....

The problem in ((BaseType<T>)data)
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'BaseType<TEntity>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'BaseType<T>'

Actually I need convert T to 'B<T> : where T : B<T>'

Comment: @sh1ng: Consider having a nongeneric base type, so that say `BaseType<T> : BaseType` - and put any methods which don't depend on `T` into that. It can make life a lot easier.

Comment: I know, but it's artifact....
If I can't create any hook I will use Reflection method call.

But now I'm thinking about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
static bool IsBaseType<T>()
{
    var t = typeof(T);

    do
    {
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseType<>))
        {
            return true;
        }

        t = t.BaseType;
    }
    while (t != null);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: 10x for replies! But I need additional feature. public void Method<T>(T data) Exec BaseType<> method on Data... I my use Reflection, but I prefer type conversion to BaseType<>. Is It possible?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern in this case is to have a non-generic base type of the generic base type.  If your method doesn't involve the type parameter, then you're done.  If it does, you could add a non-generic method that does a typecast, similar to Object.Equals:

```
public abstract class ReallyBaseType
{
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
    public abstract void SomeMethodWithParameter(object o);
}

public abstract class BaseType<TEntity> : ReallyBaseType
    where TEntity : BaseType<TEntity>
{
    public override void SomeMethodWithParameter(object o)
    {
        SomeMethodWithParameter((TEntity)o);
    }

    public abstract void SomeMethodWithParameter(TEntity entity);
}

public class AnyType : BaseType<AnyType>
{
    public override void SomeMethod() { }

    public override void SomeMethodWithParameter(AnyType entity) { }
}
```

Then, you can just check the actual type of data:

```
public void Method<T>(T data)
{
    if (data is ReallyBaseType)
    {
        ((ReallyBaseType)(object)data).SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I think you're stuck using reflection, then.  If you want to be able to write code against the concrete type, you could create a generic method and invoke it using reflection:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static MethodInfo innerMethodDefinition =
        typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("InnerMethod");

    public void Method(object data)
    {
        var t = data.GetType();
        while (t != null &&
            !(t.IsGenericType &&
            t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseType<>)))
        {
            t = t.BaseType;
        }
        if (t != null &&
            t.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssignableFrom(data.GetType()))
        {
            innerMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(
                t.GetGenericArguments()[0]).Invoke(this, new object[] { data });
        }
    }


    public void InnerMethod<TEntity>(TEntity data)
        where TEntity : BaseType<TEntity>
    {
        // Here you have the object with the correct type
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that, but It's imposable in the current project(((